# VMware Workstation 16 pro Menu Tab Size Change!

Tags: vmware

I installed VMware Workstation 16 Pro on my laptop running Ubuntu 21.10 with gnome 40.4. Everything was working fine until yesterday when I updated the software and VMware Workstation showed a bug on the upper menu tab:

[image]

Notice how the height of the "pause" and other button icons are abnormally large.

I tried troubleshooting by deleting the application and re-installing it 5 times, running distro and package updates, but there is no change.

If anyone out there ran into this same issue or know how to solve it, can you please don't hesitate.

Thank you!

Comment: This sounds like more an issue with VMware Workstation than Ubuntu specifically. Perhaps someone on [the VMWare discussion board](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Workstation-Pro/bd-p/3023) can offer a solution or confirm that it's a known bug with the recent update 

Comment: Thank you @matigo I just posted the issue in that community as well. Thank you for the suggestion!